# Laravel NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, symfony, laravel

I'm Learning laravel php framework and I'm having a problem.
I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.codeforest.net/laravel-4-tutorial-validation-frontend/)
And I'm having problem with:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException

and

> Class App\controllers\Admin\AuthController does not exist

I tried to do

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and

```
artisan dump-autoload
```

but nothing helped.

[Here's the link](https://github.com/wojjaskula/laravel_tutorial) of the repository on Github

Comment: when in doubt about class not found error after composer dump-autoload, goto `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` and search for the class. it may happen that you have some typo in namespace or whatever but if it is register there, then you will know what to add.

Comment: have you added the route in ur routes file

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you give more details on which route this throwing the exception
2. Take a look at http://laravel.com/docs/installation on how to setup Laravel 4, see if you have missed any steps

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are case sensitive:

You must change:

```
Route::get('admin/logout', array(
  'as' => 'admin.logout',
  'uses' => 'App\controllers\Admin\AuthController@getLogout'
));
```

to

```
Route::get('admin/logout', array(
  'as' => 'admin.logout',
  'uses' => 'App\Controllers\Admin\AuthController@getLogout'
));
```

Comment: If you `composer install` you'll get the vendor.

Comment: Thanks Guys , that worked on xampp.
I assumed that i will start new repo with L4 basics to don't have that simple problems. 
So i will delete that  old repo

Answer (score 0):

In file BaseController.php

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
```

In file AuthController.php

```
use App\Controllers\BaseController;
```